# How to spy on method with overload signature in karma/jasmine?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am working with angular associated with karma + jasmine for unit test.

I have a method in an `HttpService` that has overload signatures such as:

```
  public sendRequest<T>(path: string, observable?: false): Promise<T>;
  public sendRequest<T>(path: string, observable?: true): Observable<T>;
  public sendRequest<T>(path: string, observable = false): Promise<T> | Observable<T> {
```

In this method I am doing a check on the `observable` parameter and return an `Observable` if it set to true, and a `Promise` otherwise.

However, in the units tests of some components that are calling this service and this method, when I try to spy on this method and mock its return value in my tests, such as:

```
      const spySendRequest = spyOn(service["httpService"], "sendRequest").and.returnValue(
        Promise.resolve(resultExpected)
      );
```

I get this error message :

```
Argument of type 'Promise<{}[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<unknown>'.
  Type 'Promise<{}[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<unknown>': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more.
```

I am lost. What can I do?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: No, I'm still struggling with this

Comment: The issue here is that it doesn’t trigger the correct overload as the spy doesn’t control that (you’re just returning a promise there). I would need to see more, but you’d need to make the correct call to that function first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `as any` cast.

```
const spySendRequest = spyOn(service["httpService"], "sendRequest").and.returnValue(
        Promise.resolve(resultExpected) as any
      )
```

Also, instead of `returnValue`, you can use `resolveTo`

```
const spySendRequest = spyOn(service["httpService"], "sendRequest").and.resolveTo(
        resultExpected as any
      )
```

`resolveTo` gets rid of the `Promise.resolve(`. There is also `rejectWith` which would get rid of the `Promise.reject(`.